# Events not shown if they started before current view start date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Using Fullcalendar I have events that start before the current view (for instance week view, listWeek) and end inside the current view, but they are not displayed in the current view. Is there any way showing ending events that do not start in the current view?

my setup code is:

`// create calendar
$this.fullCalendar({
firstDay: weekday,
defaultView: (viewportWidth < 700) ? 'listWeek' : defaultview,
... and more ...
});`

Comment: Would be good if you could provide more code, maybe a working example?

Comment: Do you mean they end within current view but aren't showing because start is before?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, that's what I mean

Comment: So do you make a server request for each view change? Or is data local? Not showing any events source

Comment: Events are loaded via ajax. The default view is week, changing to month and back to week won't show that event either.

Comment: I'll take that back. going from week to month to week results in the ending event being shown... I got an idea how to fix it, thanks